# Implementing Primary NTP Server (GPS Receiver)

Tags: c, server, ntp

I'm trying to implement an NTP server based on an NMEA GPS Receiver. I'm not sure what to fill the root delay field with.

I've read the [NTPv4 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905) and it's written that root delay is the total round-trip delay to the reference clock.

If I'm working with a secondary server, root delay can be calculated from the time difference between the timestamps when making the packet requests with the reference server (am I correct?).

But I'm not sure what to fill it with if I'm using a GPS Receiver as the reference clock, should I fill it with 0 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend largely on how you're setting the time in your server from the GPS. If you're reading the NMEA sentence, interpreting it and setting the clock, the root delay would be the time taken to do that. But it wouldn't be a very good clock; there's a lot of non-deterministic delays (jitter) involved in reading RS232 (assuming that is how you're connected to the GPS).

You can use the 1 pulse per second output of a GPS receiver to fix that. It's normally on the Data Carrier Detect pin. Using a proper RS232 port (not a USB one) you can have the server's clock synchronised to that (DCD can be used to raise an interrupt), so now you get very good alignment to GPS time. This could certainly be done in Solaris (a native part of the kernel), and in Linux too (http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/ConfiguringNMEARefclocks). If you're doing this then I think that the root delay would be small, but there's the matter of the OS and hardware's response time to interrupts.

EDIT

According to [this NTP docs page](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/NTPRelatedDefinitions),

> Root Delay
>
> This is the total roundtrip delay to the primary reference source at 
>   the root of the synchronization subnet, in seconds. Note that this 
>   variable can take on both positive and negative values, depending on 
>   clock Precision and Skew.

So with 1PPS it's going to be pretty low. So far as I can tell it's a field that a secondary NTP server uses to tell its clients what its delay to a reference clock is. So if you have a 1PPS locked GPS time source, you are a reference clock. In which case, perhaps zero is correct enough; I don't think that NTP can achieve cross-network time synchronisation accuracies (1ms at best) better than the IRQ response time of a computer (< 50us hopefully with a good CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT linux kernel with nothing else going on).

Comment: Yes, I used the PPS output to synchronize the actual second because I read that it was very accurate. So, in this case, the root delay would be the OS and hardware's response time to the interrupt generated by the PPS pulse? Any idea how I should calculate that? Or is it small enough to be ignored?